# magento - nominal product show zero in subtotal shipping fee

Tags: magento, recurring

I have written a recurring payment module with asiapay payment,

however when i was in checkout progress, **the shipping fee and subtotal is zero**, although the actual fee will show up in the section below subtotal which is called "nominal item total",

it is still confusing for customer that the shipping fee is zero but it appears some value again in the last step.

---

Also , i am **using table rate (price VS destintaion)**....

at the step 3 SHipping method, it becomes worse that it did not find any shipping method...i am not allowed to move the step4!

So i would like to know how can i **hardcode set the subtotal and shipping fee** for nominal item checkout?

Answer (score 0):

Shipping in: app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Nominal/Shipping.php